# Executing executable remotely on Linux?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I've built my executable for ARM Linux, I then transferred to my `/bin` folder on my raspberry pi and connected with ssh. However, when I attempt to run it by just calling the file name in ssh it tells me the file is not found but I can see it when I execute `ls`.

Comment: Add executable permissions with `chmod` if you haven't already.

Comment: Does it run successfully if you provide the complete path- /bin/<fliename>

Comment: @kv.333 it's permissions are 755 so yes.

Comment: @JacobMason, as previously requested, if /bin/<filename> runs successfully, /bin is not in $PATH. Can you please try and get back?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ln -s /bin/ur_exe /usr/bin/ur_exe`

`/bin` is not in `$PATH` by default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Permissions

Make sure the permissions are set correctly (`sudo chmod +x <filename>`).

2. Paths

Make sure you're actually referencing a valid path (try executing via `/bin/<filename>` and not just by typing `<filename>`).

No luck?

3. Dependencies (shared libraries, program interpreter, etc.)

You might be dealing with missing dependencies because you've compiled the executable on a different system. Try recompiling on the target platform or satisfy any missing dependencies by moving the right files to the right locations.

To see which files and locations that might be, run `ldd <filename>` or `readelf -l <filename>`. Make sure that the output of `ldd` only contains valid paths.